# Serialport.js in Node-webkit (nw.js) on Win 7

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

How does one get serialport to work with nw.js on Windows?

I have seen a [bunch](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/126) of [articles](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/issues/374) on the web about compiling with node-pre-gyp, but can't get that to work. Also, the targets seem to be conflicting between serialport and nw.js. So I'm pretty confused.

Does anyone have step by step instructions on how to do this? I am a node rookie.

Windows 7
nw running nodejs v1.2.0 (the latest nw.exe)

Comment: you got it to work? i having the same problem, it seems the current version of nw and node serialport is not compatible? or buggy?

Comment: No. I switched to using a traditional node client-server approach, talking between the two with socket.io. Not nearly as nice. So if you have ideas??

Comment: not sure it helps, but i did this and it solves my problem https://github.com/nwjs/nw-gyp/issues/69, try to run ur command prompt in adminstrator mode

Comment: Thanks. It is defs worth a try.