# building serialport.js with nw.gyp for nw.js

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js, node-serialport

I'm trying to package **serialport.js** with my **nw.js app**. I'm having a hard time building **serialport.js** for **nw.js**.

I've installed **serialport.js** in my **"app\resource\node_modules"** using npm.

I've also installed **nw.gyp** globally **"npm install nw-gyp -g"**

Then I changed directory to **"app\resource\node_modules\serialport"** where the **binding.gyp** is located and tried to rebuild serialport with nw-gyp **"nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.12.3"**

This is the error I got:
**Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp**

[image]

Any Ideas how I can get passed this problem?

Other's seem to have similar problems:
[Serialport.js in Node-webkit (nw.js) on Win 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085097/serialport-js-in-node-webkit-nw-js-on-win-7)

I also saw the same error happening with a different node module:
[Building node-sqlite3 with nw-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228226/building-node-sqlite3-with-nw-gyp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open *node_modules/serialport/binding.gyp*, you need make some changes...

**before:**

```
  "target_name": "action_after_build",
  "type": "none",
  "dependencies": [ "<(module_name)" ],
  "copies": [
    {
      "files": [ "<(PRODUCT_DIR)/<(module_name).node" ],
      "destination": "<(module_path)"
```

**after:**

```
  "target_name": "action_after_build",
  "type": "none",
  "dependencies": [ "serialport" ],
  "copies": [
    {
      "files": [ "<(PRODUCT_DIR)/serialport.node" ],
      "destination": "."
```

And change *module_path* in *node_modules/serialport/package.json* for:

```
"module_path": "./build/{configuration}/",
```

Finally, run **nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.12.3**

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading npm works! Give a try

**npm install npm@6 -g**

Comment: This is because node-gyp changed to Python 3. But nw-gyp still uses Python 2.7.